# Excel formulae to recognise hh:mm

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell `A1` with `00:40`. I would like to write a formulae to recognise this as a hh:mm.

Apparently this formulae does not work: `=if(A1="00:40",1,0)`. I get the result as 0, not 1. Is there anyway to get this excel formulae to return as 1?

I have other cells `A2=00:42`, `A3=text`, `A4=00.50`, `A6=text`, and `A7=00.55`. Is it possible to have a formulae to extract only the times and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment you added on JDunkerley's answer, here is what you can try:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)-2,5)
```

This will return some text.

Note that you could also use the `TIMEVALUE` function to convert this to a time (using `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to extract hours and minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=If(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm")="00:40",1,0)
```

Comment: Sorry to add on. I have A2 00:42, A3 text A4 00.50 A6 text A7 00.55. Is it possible to have a formulae to extract only timing and ignore the text.

Comment: Yes, it is A1-INT(A1) with give you the time component

Comment: One other option is to do something like 100 * HOUR(A1) + MINUTE(A2), to extract just the time part

Comment: If I understand correctly you are saying that some cells (A3,A6) contain text and others times? To extract times to another column try `=N(A2)` in B2 copied down, that will give zero for text values, custom format as `[hh]:mm;;` to display times correctly but zeroes as blanks (assumes no zero times)

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix, append +0 to the time

=if(A1="00:40"+0,1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Put an apostrophe before the text.

Eg '00:40

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way? I have a ton of data with different timing that I would like to extract.

Answer (score 0):

In speadsheet formulae, you can use `TIMEVALUE()` :
`IF(A1=TIMEVALUE("00:40"),1,0)`

In VBA, just use the standard time separator: `#`:
`If range("A1") = #00:40# then`